# Fire an event before a div loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

Im trying to write a JQuery code that executes just before a div is shown on the page. Look at the code below, it will help you understand my question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.article').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', "#ec5252").fadeTo('medium', 0.8);
        $(this).find('.articleHead h1').css('color', '#ffffff');
        $(this).find('.articleDetails p').css('color', '#ffffff');
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff').fadeTo('medium',1.0);
        $(this).find('.articleHead h1').css('color', '#414141');
        $(this).find('.articleDetails p').css('color', '#a2a2a2');
    }).on('click', function(){          
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $(location).attr('href','article.php?articleId='+id);       
    }).on('beforeShow', function(){
        alert('bout to show');
    }).on('afterShow', function(){
        alert('just shown');
    });
});
```

As you can see, there a couple of events specified for the .article class. However i would like to write a code that executes just before each div with .article class shows on the web page and after the div shows. This code does not work for the beforeShow and afterShow events only, it however works for the first three events, i.e mouseenter, mouseleave and click.

Comment: Your snippet has javascript in the html box and no html.

Comment: I would guess it should not be part of the $(document).ready function, but in a separate function before...

Comment: Well the snippet is just an example of the jquery code i'm working with. the html that goes with that code would however be <div class="article"></div> @Jamiec

Comment: @HappyHamburger let me try that. Thank you

Comment: @user2497008 - a snippet is to demonstrate some working (or not working) code, its functional like jsfiddle. If you just want to put some code in your question just highlight and click the code button. Ive updated your question.

Comment: However, that does not work @HappyHamburger.

Comment: @Jamiec thank you. I will take note of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `beforeShow` and `afterShow` are not default events. They would not work unless they were added to jQuery. For an example of that see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkmurray/drv5w/2/). Keep in mind that if you use that approach your `.article` elements will need to be hidden (`display: none;`) by default, and you will have to manually call `.show` on them.

However, if you get to the point where you're manually calling `show` on these DOM elements then you've already got a perfectly good place to call whatever function you'd like before the show call.